# Not able to get label from selected option Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box which I am using with an angular object as the value i.e.

```
{identityName:'Passport',identityId:1}

 <select name="identityProof" ng-model="identityProof" ng-change="changeProofOfIdentity()" ng-options="identity as identity.identityName for identity in identityProofList track by identity.identityId"  id="identityProofList"  class="form-control" data-placeholder="" size="1"></select>
```

I have Done this setup so I can get identity id and identity label in ng-onchange function.
As you can see I have used `track by identity.identityId` I wanted to select the option by only by identityId only i did

```
$scope.identityProof = {identityId:userDetails.identityId,identityName:""};
```

Now the option with the given value get selected, but when I try to get the $scope.identityProof i.e. select box value, I only get the identityId, not the identityName, as I can see the option selected have both the name and values, 
how can I get both? 
Do I need to manage it by using jquery or javascript by getting the label of the selected value and passing it as identityName? 
Or there is an option by which I can reload the selected object to have both the values?

Comment: as is stated in the documentation for [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), >"Be careful when using `select as` and `track by` in the same expression."    You really don't need the `identity as` part of your `ng-options` clause at all, and it probably causes some cases where a selection is left with no value at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple select instead of `ng-option`. See the following example and let me know.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select name="identityProof" ng-model="identityProof"  size="1">
  <option ng-repeat="identity in identityProofList" value="{{identity}}">
  {{identity.identityName}}
  </option>
</select>
<span ng-if="identityProof">Selected value = {{identityProof}}</span>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.identityProofList = [{'identityName':'Passport','identityId':1}];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to AngularJS, why ng-option should be used over ng-repeat :
1.more flexibility in how the <select>'s model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression.
2. reduced memory consumption by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance
3. increased render speed by creating the options in a documentFragment instead of individually
And I think you didn't get my question, I want to select an option in the select box by value.` {identityName:'Passport',identityId:1}` is just an example of identity proof object, Please re-read the question